# Issue using Flash Debug Player in VM Windows Vista instance on OSX Lab machine

Tags: windows, windows-vista, flash, debug, debugger

I have a MacMini running Lion that our developers use for testing. It has three different versions of Windows installed as Virtual Machines on it. I have been trying to install the Flash Debug Player to a Windows Vista VM. I am successful with the installation but when I open a flash video in IE Flash opens up a dialog box asking where is the Debugger or hhost application running. I have tried all forms of trouble shooting this including reinstalling older and newer versions of the Active X controller, looking for a mm.cfg file has not seemed to be created seeing as how I can not find it in the specified locations. Any insight as to whether this issue is a compatibility issue between Flash and Vista, or is it an issue caused by the fact that it's a Virtual Machine.

!(http://blog.air4android.com/wp-content/uploads/blog.air4android.com/2011/04/debugger.jpg)